# Let $F$ be an extension field over $K$ , if $[F(x):K(x)]$ is finite , then is $F$ also a finite extension over $K$ ?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$  be an extension field over $K$ such that $F(x)$ is a finite extension over $K(x)$ ; then is it true that $[F:K]$ is also finite ? ( I know about the converse , that if $F/K$ is a finite extension then so is $F(x)/K(x)$  and $[F:K]=[F(x):K(x)]$ holds ) Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: See lemma 3, p. 52 in [Introduction to the Theory of Algebraic Functions of One Variable](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ga5wAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=%22%5BL(x):K(x)%5D%22&source=bl&ots=ITodZB04Mg&sig=nyJ1BCJv0K3chBHob5vUkhXw6FI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic56DAn97WAhWHKsAKHfcDDM0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22%5BL(x)%3AK(x)%5D%22&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $V$ is a $K$-vector space and $E/K$ is a field extension, then $\dim_E(V\otimes_K E) = \dim_K V$.

Apply that to $V = F$ and $E = K(x)$.

---

An elementary version : suppose $[F:K]$ is infinite, and $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ is an infinite family of linearly independent elements of $F$. Suppose they have a linear relation in $F(x)$ over $K(x)$, and try to reduce to the case $\sum_i P_ix_i = 0$ with $P_i\in K[x]$ such that the $P_i$ are not all divisible by $X$.

Then try to conclude.

Comment: Sorry , but I do not know tensor products ; is there a more elementary way to do this ?

Comment: I added an elementary sketch of proof, see if you can use it.